# Spark performing RDD.zip() and RDD.join() slowly

Tags: apache-spark

I`m trying to do a simple sentiment classification using Apache Spark. I'm starting out with a textfile containing the line number, a target (score) and a review text:

> lineNumber[;]0[;]this is a review.

which I split in two RDDs like so

```
    scores = lines.map(lambda line: (line.split("[;]")[0], line.split("[;]")[1]))
    reviews = lines.map(lambda line: (line.split("[;]")[0], line.split("[;]")[2]))
```

I`m performing some operations on the review RDD (like splitting in words, removing stop words etc), and then try to build the TFIDF:

```
    hash = HashingTF().transform(reviews.values())
    idf = IDF().fit(hash)
    tfidf = idf.transform(hash)
    f = reviews.keys().zip(tfidf)
```

afterwards, i want to join the reviews containing the TFIDF with the scores and do classsification.

```
    reviewsAndScores = scores.join(f).values()
```

However, both of the of the above mentioned operations (TFIDF+Zip, Join) take quite a long time on my machine that i start with 6G driver and 6G executor memory. On a relatively small file (330MB) both of the taks will take 1hour each.
For the join, the spark ui tells me that it gets an input of 427MB and needs to shuffle write 178.4MB. However, I`m not really sure what that means.

Do you have any hints why these operations are so slow?

Answer (score 0):

The run time for the

```
join()
```

method is not surprising - given it requires n**2 operations.  Now the zip() is harder to understand - but likely due to memory constraints.  There is a fair bit of overhead involved memory wise.

You might consider splitting up the data into like-partitioned segments and then using

```
foreachPartition()
```

But again - also consider getting more memory.  First off: you can reduce the memory on the driver and give more to the worker: e.g. 3GB and 9 GB